# Как получить все текстовые ссылки с текста?

Tags: php

Всем привет. Проблема. Есть переменная.

```
$text = 'В нашей строке присутсвуют следующие ссылки: http://snipcode.ru, ftp://php.net и https://google.com';
```

Как с этой переменной получить все ссылки в массив?

Пробовал так

```
preg_match_all('/<a[^>(href=)]+href="http:\/\/(www\.)?hashcode.ru"[^>]+>([A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9 ]+)<\/a>/isu', $text, $array);
print_r($array);
```

В итоге получил массив - `Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) [2] => Array ( ) )`

Но что-то я с этого массива никак не могу глянуть, какие там ссылки.

Пробую посмотреть ссылку `print_r($array[0]);` получаю `Array ( )`
Помогите разобраться, в php не силен. Что смог накопать, тем делюсь.

Comment: мне кажется у вас ошибка в паттерне

Comment: Есть маленькое подозрение, что Вы бездумно копипастнули решение из старого вопроса на SO.

Comment: @Other угу hashcode.ru если бы думно то я бы вопрос не задавал. А так что то в гугле все питаются с текстовых ссылок сделать клабельные. А мне нужно просто их собрать в одном месте.

Comment: в вашей строке нет вхождения hashcode.ru)

Comment: @Grundy нет там ничего, там ссылка должна начинаться с www или с // а мне этого не нужно, просто найти все ссылки в тексте и в один массив собрать их. Вот и все.

Comment: Ответ уже дан, но все же, слово "присутсвуют " в русском языке пишется как "присутсТвуют ".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С предположением, что отделять ссылки могут только запятые и пробельные символы:

```
$text = 'В нашей строке присутсвуют следующие ссылки: http://snipcode.ru, ftp://php.net и https://google.com'; 
preg_match_all('#(?:https?|ftp)://[^\s\,]+#i', $text, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Результат:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(18) "http://snipcode.ru"
    [1]=>
    string(13) "ftp://php.net"
    [2]=>
    string(18) "https://google.com"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = 'В нашей строке присутсвуют следующие ссылки: http://snipcode.ru, ftp://php.net и https://google.com';

preg_match_all("_(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:/[^\s]*)?_iuS", $text, $urls);

var_dump($urls);
```

https://repl.it/GfwT/0

Comment: `http://example.org?id=5` - берёт только домен. `http://example.org/?id=5, ...` цепляет запятую, хотя у автора запятые используются для разделения списка.