# Покупка в кредит от Тинькофф банка интеграция curl

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

Делаю интеграцию покупки в кредит от Тинькова.
Через form post все работает идеально. А через curl post не получается.
print_r во всех случаях возвращает единицу. При этом в страничку каким то образом вставляется вот такой текст:

> The response to the request can be found under this URI using a GET method.

В this URL вставлена ссылка при нажатии на которую открывается нужная мне страничка. Но как ее достать через переменную, что бы можно было с ней дальше работать, понять не могу.

Что то мне подсказывает, что это я шланг и что-то делаю не так.

```
$object = [
    "shopId" => "test_online",
    "showcaseId" => "test_online",
    "itemPrice_0" => 14499.00,
    "itemName_0" => 'Машинка на больших колесах',
    "itemQuantity_0" => 1,
    "sum" => 14499.00,
];

$fields_string = http_build_query($object);

$ch = curl_init();
$url = "https://loans-qa.tcsbank.ru/api/partners/v1/lightweight/create";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
$return = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($return);
```

Comment: `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`

Comment: RETURNTRANSFER - сам доехал открыл документацию по curl.

А вот как раскрасить этот ответ. Вот такой html отдает curl: 

<body>The response to the request can be found under <a href="https://loans-qa.tcsbank.ru/applications/online/5791380c-98cf-43a6-a136-24f37dd875d1">this URI</a> using a GET method.</body>

Как от туда достать ссылку?

Comment: @Ruslan Ну по регулярке можно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/644688/

Comment: ни когда не применяйте [регулярки к html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self%20-contained-tags) используйте DomDocument

Comment: В итоге использовал simple_html_dom.

 $html = str_get_html($return);
foreach($html->find('a') as $e) {
    $link = $e->href;
}